# Create a new column that stores a ratio score in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
    RANK  STA  RUN  BIB       NAME  FINISH  FINISH.1  FINISH.2            COURSE
0      1    3    3    1  ingenting     3.0      0.00       NaN           LØYPE 1
1      2    8    2    3  ingenting     4.0      1.97       NaN           LØYPE 3
2      3    9    3    3  ingenting     5.0      2.06       NaN           LØYPE 1
3      4    2    2    1  ingenting     6.0      3.21       NaN  STRAIGHT-GLIDING
4      5    5    1    2  ingenting     6.0      3.32       NaN           LØYPE 1
5      6    1    1    1  ingenting     6.0      3.34       NaN  STRAIGHT-GLIDING
6      7    4    4    1  ingenting     6.0      3.43       NaN           LØYPE 1
7      8   13    7    3  ingenting     6.0      3.48       NaN  STRAIGHT-GLIDING
8      9   12    6    3  ingenting     6.0      3.65       NaN  STRAIGHT-GLIDING
9     10   11    5    3  ingenting     NaN      4.19       NaN  STRAIGHT-GLIDING
10    11    6    2    2  ingenting     7.0      4.20       NaN           LØYPE 3
11    12   14    3    2  ingenting     7.0      4.30       NaN  STRAIGHT-GLIDING
12    13   10    4    3  ingenting     8.0      5.14       NaN           LØYPE 2
13    14    7    1    3  ingenting     8.0      5.75       NaN           LØYPE 3
```

The Data Frame consists of different athletes (BIB) in different courses (COURSES). Each BIB also has his own RUN number. My main interest is the FINISH column. Now I want to obtain the following:

- I want to find the **first** STRAIGHT-GLIDING FINISH time for each BIB.
- Next, I want "store" this as a reference time.
- Next, for each observation (13 in this example) I want to compute this BIB's FINISH time subtracted from this BIB's STRAIGHT-GLIDING time.

The solution should add a new column with this information, for each observation. To give you an example, in observation 0, the FINISH time is 3.0 and his first STRAIGHT-GLIDING time is '3.21'. I, therefore, want to create a value 3.0 - 3.21. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my answer. It's a little longer :)

```
# Create filter for 'STRAIGHT-GLIDING'
sg_filt = df['COURSE'] == 'STRAIGHT-GLIDING'

# Create 'STRAIGHT-GLIDING' only dataframe using filter
sg_only = df.loc[sg_filt].copy()

# Preview new DataFrame
sg_only

  Rank  STA RUN BIB NAME    FINISH  FINISH.1    COURSE
3   4   2   2   1   ingenting   6.0 3.21    STRAIGHT-GLIDING
5   6   1   1   1   ingenting   6.0 3.34    STRAIGHT-GLIDING
7   8   13  7   3   ingenting   6.0 3.48    STRAIGHT-GLIDING
8   9   12  6   3   ingenting   6.0 3.65    STRAIGHT-GLIDING
9   10  11  5   3   ingenting   NaN 4.19    STRAIGHT-GLIDING
11  12  14  3   2   ingenting   7.0 4.30    STRAIGHT-GLIDING

# Create DataFrame on only first times per BIB
first_times = sg_only[sg_only.groupby(['BIB','COURSE']).cumcount() == 0][['BIB','FINISH']].copy()

# Change column name on first_times dataFrame for merge
first_times.rename(columns={'FINISH':'Reference_Time'},inplace=True)

# Merge original DataFrame with first_times DataFrame to get reference time
final_df = pd.merge(df,first_times,on='BIB',how='left')


   Rank STA RUN BIB NAME     FINISH FINISH.1    COURSE  Reference_Time
0   1   3   3   1   ingenting   3.0  0.00    LØYPE 1            6.0
1   2   8   2   3   ingenting   4.0  1.97    LØYPE 3            6.0
2   3   9   3   3   ingenting   5.0  2.06    LØYPE 1            6.0
3   4   2   2   1   ingenting   6.0  3.21    STRAIGHT-GLIDING   6.0
4   5   5   1   2   ingenting   6.0  3.32    LØYPE 1            7.0
5   6   1   1   1   ingenting   6.0  3.34    STRAIGHT-GLIDING   6.0
6   7   4   4   1   ingenting   6.0  3.43    LØYPE 1            6.0
7   8   13  7   3   ingenting   6.0  3.48    STRAIGHT-GLIDING   6.0
8   9   12  6   3   ingenting   6.0  3.65    STRAIGHT-GLIDING   6.0
9   10  11  5   3   ingenting   NaN  4.19    STRAIGHT-GLIDING   6.0
10  11  6   2   2   ingenting   7.0  4.20    LØYPE 3            7.0
11  12  14  3   2   ingenting   7.0  4.30    STRAIGHT-GLIDING   7.0
12  13  10  4   1   ingenting   8.0  5.14    LØYPE 2            6.0
13  14  7   1   1   ingenting   8.0  5.75    LØYPE 3            6.0

# Create FINISH_TIME column 
final_df['FINISH_TIME'] = final_df['FINISH'] - final_df['Reference_Time']

   Rank STA RUN BIB NAME    FINISH  FINISH.1    COURSE  Reference_Time  FINISH_TIME
0   1   3   3   1   ingenting   3.0  0.00   LØYPE 1             6.0    3.0
1   2   8   2   3   ingenting   4.0  1.97   LØYPE 3             6.0   -2.0
2   3   9   3   3   ingenting   5.0  2.06   LØYPE 1             6.0   -1.0
3   4   2   2   1   ingenting   6.0  3.21   STRAIGHT-GLIDING    6.0    0.0
4   5   5   1   2   ingenting   6.0  3.32   LØYPE 1             7.0   -1.0
5   6   1   1   1   ingenting   6.0  3.34   STRAIGHT-GLIDING    6.0    0.0
6   7   4   4   1   ingenting   6.0  3.43   LØYPE 1             6.0    0.0
7   8   13  7   3   ingenting   6.0  3.48   STRAIGHT-GLIDING    6.0    0.0
8   9   12  6   3   ingenting   6.0  3.65   STRAIGHT-GLIDING    6.0    0.0
9   10  11  5   3   ingenting   NaN  4.19   STRAIGHT-GLIDING    6.0    NaN
10  11  6   2   2   ingenting   7.0  4.20   LØYPE 3             7.0    0.0
11  12  14  3   2   ingenting   7.0  4.30   STRAIGHT-GLIDING    7.0    0.0
12  13  10  4   1   ingenting   8.0  5.14   LØYPE 2             6.0    2.0
13  14  7   1   1   ingenting   8.0  5.75   LØYPE 3             6.0    2.0
```

Comment: Thank you! Very close :D The only thing is that you used the FINISH.1 to set the reference time; It should have been the FINISH column. So for the first observation, the reference time should have been 6.0.

Comment: Is there a simple way to fix this? I liked your approach

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution (I hope I understood you correctly):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

previousBib = ""
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    currentBib = df.BIB.to_numpy()[i]
    
    if (currentBib != previousBib):
        instances_BibI = df.loc[df.BIB == currentBib]
        instances_BibI = instances_BibI.sort_values(by=["RUN"])             # To ensure that the first gliding finish is the first race with that finish
        first_StraightGliding_Finish = instances_BibI.loc[instances_BibI.COURSE == "STRAIGHT-GLIDING"].FINISH_1.to_numpy()[0]
        
    df.at[i, 'FINISH_2'] = df.iloc[i, 5] - first_StraightGliding_Finish
    
    previousBib = currentBib
```

where `df` is your example dataframe

My sample output (sorted by BIB and RUN) is as follows:

```py
    RANK  STA   RUN BIB NAME    FINISH  FINISH_1    FINISH_2    COURSE
5   6     1     1   1   Olle    6.0     3.34        2.66        STRAIGHT-GLIDING
3   4     2     2   1   Olle    6.0     3.21        2.66        STRAIGHT-GLIDING
0   1     3     3   1   Olle    3.0     0.00       -0.34        Loop1
6   7     4     4   1   Olle    6.0     3.43       2.66         Loop1
4   5     5     1   2   Olle    6.0     3.32       1.70         Loop1
10  11    6     2   2   Olle    7.0     4.20       2.70         Loop3
11  12    14    3   2   Olle    7.0     4.30       2.70         STRAIGHT-GLIDING
13  14    7     1   3   Olle    8.0     5.75       3.81         Loop3
1   2     8     2   3   Olle    4.0     1.97       -0.19        Loop3
2   3     9     3   3   Olle    5.0     2.06       0.81         Loop1
12  13    10    4   3   Olle    8.0     5.14       3.81         Loop2
9   10    11    5   3   Olle    NaN     4.19       NaN          STRAIGHT-GLIDING
8   9     12    6   3   Olle    6.0     3.65       1.81         STRAIGHT-GLIDING
7   8     13    7   3   Olle    6.0     3.48       1.81         STRAIGHT-GLIDING
```

where the `FINISH_2` column is the subtracted time value you wanted to calculate